The post created through v2 APIs can not be searched by X search tool
I am facing with a strange case.
I created posts with v2 APIs successfully, but those posts can be searched by my account which is a public account and those posts are not protected posts. In terms of posts created directly on the X platform, we can search them normally. Does anyone know the reason and any idea for solutions ?
This is the account (@thothohtot50484). You can try to search almost posts which are not found by X search tool
I expect to be able to search all posts created by Twitter v2 apis on the X search tool.

